# How to hide the dropdown menu after a scrollTo event on the same page

Tags: jquery

Having a problem with a flyout menu that has links that scroll to different sections on the same page. Since it scrolls to existing content, the page doesn't reload to force the flyout menu to hide again. This isn't a huge deal for non-mobile users, but on iPads and tablets the flyout menu doesn't go away. Essentially what I would like to do is hide that menu onclick, but unhide it again when you mousover or press it afterwards.

Below is what I've been working on to try and fix it, but I've hit an impass and my brain has apparently decided that I need help.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$("ul.sub-menu li a").live('click', function() {
    // $("#subMenu").hide();
    // $("ul.sub-menu").hide();
 });
</script>
```

I created a JSBin to replicate the problem for troubleshooting. I apologize in advance for the amount of code involved, but that was as far as I could pare it down without breaking it. Hopefully, it will be a solution that someone else has dealt with already and they won't have to wade thru a lot of code to solve it.

http://jsbin.com/cotug/2/edit

**In order for it to work right, you may need to hide the HTML panel.**

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code with hide didn't work because of $ was undefined.
Try replacing $ with jQuery. Like here: http://jsbin.com/puzinoyi/1/

P.S. My assume is that noconflict is being called by one of libs you're using. As result $ becomes undefined.